# Unauthorized operation error occurs when using Boto3 to launch an EC2 instance with an IAM role

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I've read this question [How do I use Boto3 to launch an EC2 instance with an IAM role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518334/how-do-i-use-boto3-to-launch-an-ec2-instance-with-an-iam-role) and try to launch an instance with IAM role in python script. Here's the code:

```
instance = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId='ami-1a7f6d7e',
    KeyName='MyKeyPair',
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    SecurityGroups=['launch-wizard-3'],
    InstanceType='t2.micro',
    IamInstanceProfile={
        'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::627714603946:instance-profile/SSMforCC'}
)
```

However, I got this error after running the script `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the RunInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.` I found this question [how do I launch ec2-instance with iam-role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554392/how-do-i-launch-ec2-instance-with-iam-role) provides an solution for `Ruby` to solve the problem. Can anybody tell me if there's a way to solve this problem in python `Boto3`?

Comment: Does the same script work if you just remove `IamInstanceProfile`?

Comment: It does work when I remove `IamInstanceProfile`

Answer (score 4):

I would check - 
 1. If you are authenticating to AWS correctly or not - you can specify the access and secret keys explicitly in the clients.

```
client = boto3.client(
    'ec2',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
)
```

2. If the user has `ec2:runInstances` IAM permission on the resource you are trying to create.

Comment: This script works when I remove the attribute `IamInstanceProfile`. It just does not work after I add that attribute. I don't think there's something wrong with the authentication and could you please explain the second reason?

Comment: The second point relates to the permissions of the authenticated IAM user - basically if it has the required permissions. 

Since you mention it works without specifying the IamInstanceProfile, I suggest you also verify --

1. If this user has iam:passrole permission to the role you want to use. 

2. Check if the role you want to use has an instance profile arn or not - can be checked under the IAM console - if the instance profile arn is blank, it can't be used on an instance.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have sufficient privileges (`iam::PassRole`) to attach an IAM role to an instance. So attach a policy that grants you the privilege. You can attach a policy to a user only if you are an IAM admin or have sufficient privileges to attach a policy to an user.

- First [create_policy](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_policy) with the policy document that allows `PassRole`. See: [How to give ec2 instance access to s3 using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852308/how-to-give-ec2-instance-access-to-s3-using-boto3)
- Next [attach_user_policy](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.attach_user_policy) to the user