# AWS Lambda, boto3 - start instances, error while testing (not traceable)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to create a Lambda function to automatically start/stop/reboot some instances (with some additional tasks in the future).

I created the IAM role with a policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:StartInstances",
        "ec2:StopInstances",      
        "ec2:RebootInstances"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:ResourceTag/critical":"true"
        }
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:<12_digits>:instance/*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
```

The Lambda function has been granted access to the correct VPC, subnet, and security group.

I assigned the role to a new Lambda function (Python 3.9):

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

# instance IDs copied from my AWS Console 
instances = ['i-xx1', 'i-xx2', 'i-xx3', 'i-xx4']

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(str(instances))
    try:
        print('The break occurs here \u2193')
        response = ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances, DryRun=True)
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
        if 'DryRunOperation' not in str(e):
            print("You don't have permission to reboot instances.")
            raise
    try:
        response = ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances, DryRun=False)
        print(response)
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
    return response
```

I cannot find anything due to no message in the test output about where the error is. I had thought it had been a matter of time duration, then I set the time limit to 5 mins to be sure if it was a matter of time. For example:

```
Test Event Name
chc_lambda_test1

Response
{
  "errorMessage": "2022-07-30T19:15:40.088Z e037d31d-5658-40b4-8677-1935efd3fdb7 Task timed out after 300.00 seconds"
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: e037d31d-5658-40b4-8677-1935efd3fdb7 Version: $LATEST
['i-xx', 'i-xx', 'i-xx', 'i-xx']
The break occurs here ↓
END RequestId: e037d31d-5658-40b4-8677-1935efd3fdb7
REPORT RequestId: e037d31d-5658-40b4-8677-1935efd3fdb7  Duration: 300004.15 ms  Billed Duration: 300000 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 79 MB  Init Duration: 419.46 ms    
2022-07-30T19:15:40.088Z e037d31d-5658-40b4-8677-1935efd3fdb7 Task timed out after 300.00 seconds

Request ID
e037d31d-5658-40b4-8677-1935efd3fdb7
```

I had tried increasing the Lambda memory too, but it hasn't worked (it is not the case, since Max Memory Used: 79 MB).

Comment: What do you mean "no error messages"? I see an error message: `""errorMessage": "Task timed out after 300.00 seconds""`

Comment: "no message in the test output about where the error is" -> I don't know why there is a timeout - no information on what is happening on the way.

Comment: Does your subnet has access to the internet? You get a timeout, which means `start_instances` can not access the AWS API.

Comment: There is an internet gateway with 0.0.0.0/0 route attached to the VPC.

Comment: Yeah, but that does not mean the subnet has access to the internet. You want to check the route table for the subnet, it should either route to the internet gateway or a NAT.

Comment: The subnet contains route 0.0.0.0/0 as well (as I see in the Console). Is there anything else to configure?

Comment: Assuming that route actually points to the correct instance, probably not. The security group attached to the Lambda should allow outbound connectivity. Also, if you have an interface endpoint in the VPC for EC2, that should allow connectivity from the lambda.

Comment: The security group has an outbound rule (IPv4, all traffic, all protocols, all port ranges, destination 0.0.0.0/0). However, I haven't configured any endpoint. After adding it, I am getting an error (UnauthorizedOperation). I'll try to figure it out - thanks a lot!

Comment: Why is the Lambda function attached to a VPC at all? It doesn't appear to need to be. If it doesn't, then don't attach it to a VPC. If it does, then make sure that it's in a private subnet, not public subnet. As a general rule, don't modify outbound security group rules unless you really need to (and you know what you're doing).

Comment: I used the same code and it seems to be working, i

`The break occurs here ↓
An error occurred (DryRunOperation) when calling the StartInstances operation: Request would have succeeded, but DryRun flag is set.`

Comment: Solved. I have to work out the security (what to do and what to avoid), but the desired effect is achieved.

Comment: As mentioned above, you could just remove the function from the VPC entirely, since you aren't accessing any VPC resources in it at all, you are only accessing the AWS API, which is on the public Internet, not in your VPC.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason the issue occurred, is the lack of internet access to the subnet assigned to the Lambda function. I have added (as [Ervin Szilagyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7661119/ervin-szilagyi) suggested) an endpoint in the VPC (with an assignment to the subnet and security group).

The next step was to provide authorization - thanks to this idea [Unauthorized operation error occurs when using Boto3 to launch an EC2 instance with an IAM role](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47012955/9979337), I added the IAM access key and secret key to the client invocation.

```
ec2 = boto3.client(
    'ec2',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
)
```

However, **please be careful with security settings**, I am a new user (and working on my private projects at the moment), therefore, you shouldn't take this solution as secure.